# jQuery ajax call does not works for self signed certificate

Tags: java, jquery, https, self-signed

created a java HTTPS server and then created a self signed certificated using java keytool. When i hit the https url in the browser, it shows the certificate error/warnings and then everything goes fine after accepting the certificate.

But when i try to invoke that https url by using jquery ajax call, it does not proceed.But once i hit that https url in the browser and accept the certificate error/warnings, jQuery Ajax call works fine.

But i do not want to hit the https url in browser. Is there anyway to bypass the certificate error/warnings while making the jQuery ajax call for the https url.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing cross-domain Ajax calls? If yes; then you really can't do anything. Browser itself blocks that cross origin calls with invalid SSL certificate. Also you can try importing this Self signed certificate in to trusted root by following below URL:

[How To Import a Trusted Root Certification](http://www.sqlservermart.com/HowTo/Windows_Import_Certificate.aspx)

Comment: i already went through the link you suggested that works for me.But still looking if there is anyway to bypass the invalid certificate errors when making ajax call.